# How did Bartleyby/Loki recognize Rufus?

Tags: dogma

In *Dogma*, when Rufus enters the carriage, Bartleyby recognizes him instantely.

Now, Bartleyby and Loki were sent to Wisconsin when he convinced Loki to quit:

> Metatron : So once he's done with the firstborn, Loki takes his friend Bartleby out for a post-slaughter drink. And over many rounds, they get into this discussion about whether or not murder in the name of God is okay. And in the end, Bartleby convinces Loki to quit his position and take a lesser one that doesn't involve slaughter. So - very inebriated - Loki tells God he quits, throws down his fiery sword, and gives Him the finger.

We have no exact date on when the plagues of egypt happened, but we can agree that it happened centuries before Jesus was born (from Wikipedia):

> Scholars are in broad agreement that the publication of the Torah took place in the mid-Persian period (the 5th century BCE).

So, as Bartleyby/Loki were in Wisconsin and Jesus (and therefore Rufus) in the Middle East, how were they able to recognize Rufus?

Comment: I don't the answer but I have a guess. If Rufus went to heaven after his death (certainly a point of argument whether anyone including Saints and Martyrs does get to heaven until the 'last days' or not) he would be in the 'know' and might recognize the two fallen angels because of that.

Comment: That Rufus knows them is clear: _Rufus : You know what the dead do with most of their time? They watch the living. Especially in the shower._. So, he knows there were two fallen angels in Wisconsin and took a peek. Now, the other way around is not so clear.

Comment: @tgrignon well the Catholic church defines Saint as a person who is already in heaven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the boardroom scene, it is demonstrated that they know the identities and sins of everyone. That would logically also include Rufus.

Whether this is an intrinsic power of all angels is not elaborated on.